# change WordPress reply button to include posters name

Tags: wordpress, button, reply

I have a WordPress blog using a costume theme and what i would like to do is change the reply text at the end of each comment below the blog post so it includes the name of the poster of the comments.

For example if the comment user had the name of "max" the reply button would say "reply to max" instead of just reply.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out

```
<?php
$author = get_comment_author( $comment_ID );
comment_reply_link( array_merge( $args, array( 'reply_text' => __( 'Reply to '.$author.'<span>&uarr;</span>', 'twentyeleven' ), 'depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'] ) ) ); 
?>
```